# Scraping a school soccer results page. How do I remove \n\t from a dataframe and also combine several bs4.element.ResultSet?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

An ongoing project... by a python novice!!  I have created 4 "class 'bs4.element.ResultSet" called games (wins), draws, ties and custom from a school website.  I am helping the league out by scraping all the school score and aggregating.  I can not figure out how to combine those 4 element.resultsets into so I can run the rest of the program.  Right now it only save the"games (wins)" to the excel spreadsheet.  Also in the output below there are a ton of spaces - how can I get rid of those \n\t ??  Thanks so much in advance for your help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re

url = 'https://www.loomischaffee.org/athletics/teams/fall/soccer-boys/varsity'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser') 

week = soup.find(id='fsEl_5138')

games = week.find_all(class_ ='fsResultWin')
draws = week.find_all(class_ ='fsResultTie')
ties = week.find_all(class_ ='fsResultLoss')
custom = week.find_all(class_ ='fsResultCustom')

# now creating 6 lists of the data contained in the above. 
date = [games.find(class_ = 'fsDate').get_text() for games in games]
time = [games.find(class_ = 'fsTime').get_text() for games in games]
opponent = [games.find(class_ = 'fsAthleticsOpponentName').get_text() for games in games]
home_away = [games.find(class_ = 'fsAthleticsAdvantage').get_text() for games in games]
location = [games.find(class_ = 'fsAthleticsLocations').get_text() for games in games]
result = [games.find(class_ = 'fsAthleticsResult').get_text() for games in games]
score = [games.find(class_ = 'fsAthleticsScore').get_text() for games in games]

# now I turn data into a table using pandas so I can manipulate

results = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Date': date,
         'Time': time,
         'Opponent': opponent,
         'Home/Away': home_away,
         'Location' : location,
         'Result': result,
         'Score': score,
         })

print(results)
results.to_excel('results.xls')
```

Comment: use regex to replace from your string that contains \n\t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you write `.get_text()`,
you could use `.get_text().strip()` to strip off whitespace.

You are storing several columns,
which may work well enough,
you can combine them with [`zip(x, y)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) if need be.
But you might find it more convenient to ask BeautifulSoup to find the table,
and then `find_all('tr')` within the table, that is, iterate over the rows.

Consider representing (part of) a table row like this:

```
row = dict(opponent='vs. Northfield Mt. Hermon',
           advantage='Home',
           score='1-1')
```

If you have a tr object, a table row, you could easily find those values.

With that in hand, you could represent the whole table as a list of rows,
with each row being a `dict`.

Then output the rows to a spreadsheet as you've been doing.
Or `$ pip install pandas` and [you can do](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel):

```
rows = read_html_table_rows()
df = pandas.Dataframe(rows)
df.to_excel('results.xls')
```